# Is there a way to access ZFS formatted USB stick in Linux?

Tags: zfs

I have a usb stick formatted in FreeBSD as ZFS which I want to mount, copy all data and reformat as ext4.
Is there a way to perform such things in Linux?

Comment: Well, there's ZFS on Linux. See if your distro provides prebuilt modules for their official kernel builds, or just build it yourself.

Comment: BTW, some distros (e.g. debian) have a dkms package for zfs, install that and kernel headers and the zfs modules will be compiled and installed under `/lib/modules`.      Also, you will want to use the `-R` option when you `zpool import` the zpool on the USB stick, or manually set the `altroot` property (otherwise any datasets you mount, or that are auto mounted, will be mounted relative to your actual root dir instead of under, e.g., `/mnt`).